# Category and Subcategory in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm creating an ecommerce website using nodejs. Ideally, the product will have a category and subcategory. But what I'm creating should be used with any type of ecommerce website, and therefore, the subcategory field might not be needed.

In the product schema I added the subcategory field, which is related to the subcategory document. And the subcategory document is related to the category document.

My question is, how can a product be added in the database without a subcategory?

Category schema:

```
const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

Subcategory schema:

```
const subCategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    Category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required:true
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('SubCategory', subCategorySchema);
```

Product schema:

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price : {
        type: Number,
        default:0
    },
    SubCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SubCategory',
        required:true
    },
    countInStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 255
    },
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're going to have to have a required Category field in your ProductSchema and a non-required SubCategory field. This way, you'll make sure that all your products have, at least, a Category, and allow for a SubCategory to be added:

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
  },
  description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  price : {
      type: Number,
      default:0
  },
  Category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category',
    required: true
  },
  SubCategory: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'SubCategory',
      required: false
  },
  countInStock: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 255
  },
})
```

If you want to make sure that the hierarchy of the category and subcategory, you can always add some middleware validation on your pre-save:

```
productSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (this.SubCategory) {
    try {
      const check = await SubCategory.findById(this.SubCategory);
      if (!check || JSON.stringify(check.Category) !== JSON.stringify(this.Category)) {
        throw new Error('Check your Category and/or SubCategory');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: That's interesting, that might really do it.. Thanks for your reply and your time...
But I want to understand something. How does "check.Category" work?

Comment: `SubCategory.findById(this.SubCategory)` takes the `SubCategory` collection and looks for an item with the same id you introduced as the `SubCategory` you introduced in your `product` document. The result of this query is stored in `check`. So, if `check` is empty, then there `SubCategory` id introduced for this particular product isn't valid. The second condition checks for the `Category`: only if `product.Category` matches the `Category` that is meant to be the parent of `product.SubCategory`, both will be considered valid. None of this happens if no `SubCategory` is introduced in `product`.

Answer (score 1):

You Should Create Nested Categories for more simplicity just like

 **Model**

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
     },
    parentId: {
    type: String,
    },
},
{ timestamps: true }
);
```

And For Fetching Categories with their Sub-Categories

```
const categories = await Category.find({});
const categoryList = createCategories(categories); 
res.status(201).json({ 
success: true,
categoryList,
});
```

```
const createCategories = (categories, parentId = null) => {
  const categoryList = [];
  let category;
  if (parentId == undefined) {
    category = categories.filter((cat) => cat.parentId == undefined);
  } else {
    category = categories.filter((cat) => cat.parentId == parentId);
  }
  for (let cate of category) {
    categoryList.push({
      _id: cate._id,
      name: cate.name,
      children: createCategories(categories, cate._id),
    });
  }
  return categoryList;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you can wrap your reference to subcategories in array.

```
const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  categoryName: String,
  subCategoryId: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'subCategory',
  }],
}, { timestamps: true });
```